# Accidentally deleted a document from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

One of my users has accidentally deleted a document that he needs, is there any way to retrieve this document?

Comment: not if there is no backup

Comment: How do I set up a backup for future?

Comment: Please go through this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#:~:text=Go%20to%20the%20Cloud%20Firestore,the%20Google%20Cloud%20Platform%20Console.&text=Click%20Export.,button%20to%20select%20a%20bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the commenters indicated: there is no built-in way to restore a document that was deleted from Firestore.

If you didn't make an [export of the data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20Cloud%20Firestore,the%20Google%20Cloud%20Platform%20Console.&text=Click%20Export.,button%20to%20select%20a%20bucket) or otherwise backed up the document in your application code, there is no way to restore it for the user.

Comment: Thank you! I have set up an automated backup with Google Console and Cloud Scheduler